# Orchard text editor cannot save my html

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, content-management-system, tinymce, orchardcms

I'm using orchard CMS to build a website, i added a page via the orchard's text editor.
I input the following code and save:

```
<a class="tile wide imagetext bg-color-blue" href="./bootstrap-scaffolding.html">
     <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img src="content/img/My Apps.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column-text">
      <div class="text">Grid system</div>
          <div class="text">Layouts</div>
          <div class="text">Responsive design</div>
       </div>
     <span class="app-label">SCAFFOLDING</span>
</a>
```

But i find that the code is changed in text editor when open the editor again, they are:

```
<h2>Bootstrap Metro</h2>
<div class="image-wrapper"><img src="content/img/My Apps.png" /></div>
<div class="column-text">
<div class="text">Grid system</div>
<div class="text">Layouts</div>
<div class="text">Responsive design</div></div>
<a class="tile wide imagetext bg-color-blue" href="./bootstrap-scaffolding.html"><span class="app-label">SCAFFOLDING</span> </a>
```

The changed code are:

```
<a class="tile wide imagetext bg-color-blue" href="./bootstrap-scaffolding.html"><span class="app-label">SCAFFOLDING</span> </a>
```

Could you please give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it to work by changing the TinyMCE options (in orchard-tinymce.js, but you can try out TinyMceDeluxe which has some alternate methods of configuring the options).

```
, forced_root_block: false
, preformatted: true
, schema: 'html5'
, valid_children: '+a[div],+a[span]'
```

I'm pretty sure it was the "valid_children" setting that fixed the problem, but the others preceding it are things I tried first, and I had them in the config when I got to trying valid_children. You can try removing the other options and just using valid_children to see if it will work.

There is also a doctype option that might work; it controls the doctype of the iframe that TinyMCE creates. In HTML5 `<div>` elements are valid children of the a tag, so if the tinyMCE code were properly applying the doctype or schema rules we wouldn't have to set valid_children. (This is why I tried `schema: 'html5'` above, but that didn't seem to work)

Comment: Is it worth filing a bug for this?

Comment: Note, previous comment was convoluted. I meant to say: It only works if you have at least these options set: `forced_root_block:false, preformatted:true, valid_children: '+a[div],+a[span]'`. The `schema:'html5'` part may or may not be required, I didn't test without it.

Comment: @Bertrand: It depends. If it's OK to assume that anyone using TinyMce in Orchard will be fine with having their TinyMce set up to work with html5, then yeah, we should file a bug. I don't know enough about the ramifications to decide this for all Orchard users, but I am leaning towards doing it for TinyMceDeluxe, and already modified the default options in that module (not live on the gallery yet, but will be in the next release).

Comment: If you decide to file a bug I will submit a patch, or someone can lift the code from the TinyMceDeluxe repo.

Comment: FWIW I only needed the `valid_children` setting for v1.8

Answer (score 0):

It's probably TinyMCE that changes the HTML to match some TinyMCE-rules. You could disable the TinyMCE module which will give you a plain textarea into which you can enter HTML that won't be changed.

There's a [TinyMCE deluxe module](http://tinymcedeluxe.codeplex.com/) that might give you the option to change this behavior.

Comment: It's definitely TinyMCE that's modifying the HTML. You can look at the docs here to see if there is a setting you can change to stop this from happening. Some places to look first: the schema (html4/html5), doctype, or the allowed parent/child elements settings.